# finding a row in pandas through input

Tags: python, pandas

I made a small script that iterates over a certain column through a given name and prints all its rows

I would like to make it search through its rows through a user input but not have to give it its full name.. last 3 letters would be sufficient for it.

[image]

If i give it the full name, for example - H516G067U it will find that memory

If something like 67U is given it will not find it, and this is exactly what im trying to do here.

What i've tried so far

```
import pandas as pd


file = "path"
df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}", "DDR5 UDIMM")
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
sn = [x for x in df["IDC S/N"]]
memory = input("enter a number : ")
if memory in sn:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user input to be matched against the strings at any position, use the `str.contains` method. Also, if you want the query to be case-insensitive, make sure, both input and data are in the same case (e.g. using the `lower()` method on both). If I understand correctly, you don't want to just to print true or false, but return the actual rows matching the user input.

My suggeston is changing your code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


file = "path"
df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}", "DDR5 UDIMM")


memory = input("enter a number : ")
df_out = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'IDC S/N'].str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower()), :]
```

So then `df_out` would contain all the rows where the serial number matches the user input.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Yep, had a typo sorry, is now fixed

Comment: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: This means you have `NaN`s in your `IDC S/N` series. Fix it by convewrting them to strings and changing the last line above as follows: `df_out = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'IDC S/N'].fillna('nan').str.lower().str.contains(memory.lower()), :]`

Comment: Worked, Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `str` accessor:

```
import re

file = "path"
df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}", "DDR5 UDIMM")
... # set_option

# memory <- 67U
memory = re.escape(input("enter a number : "))
if df['IDC S/N'].str[-3:] == memory
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Thats because `df['IDC S/N'].str[-3:] == memory` will evaluate to a series of `True` and `False`  values. It would work if you changed as so: `if any(df['IDC S/N'].str[-3:] == memory):`. But I'm not sure that's what you want to achieve

Comment: It returns a false when correct value is entered

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `apply` is pretty useful here.

Return a TRUE/FALSE column representing if the last 3 characters is the value:

```
memory = input("enter a number : ")
df["IDC S/N"].apply(lambda x: x[-3:] == memory)
```

Return a TRUE/FALSE column representing if value is in string at all:

```
memory = input("enter a number : ")
df["IDC S/N"].apply(lambda x: memory in x)
```

If there is NaN values in your column:

```
df["IDC S/N"].apply(lambda x: memory in x if type(x) != float else x)
```

Comment: Both return TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That is probably because you have NaN-values in your column? You can either remove them or add: ```df["IDC S/N"].apply(lambda x: x[-3:] == memory if type(x) != float) ``` and ```df["IDC S/N"].apply(lambda x: memory in x if type(x) != float)```

Comment: Also I made a typo. It is fixed now

Comment: Care to explain what NaN is and how they could be removed? :)

Comment: NaN values are missing values. Checkout this guide: https://datatofish.com/dropna/

Comment: Also there's a syntax error in this one sadly, it excepts an else statement

Comment: Yes sorry. Added it to the answer now

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().